# What to choose JsonProperty or StringProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I would like to store `dict`-like data in GAE NDB (will contain up to 100 keys):

```
{u'mail@example.com': 74, u'mail2@example.com': 1, u'mail3@example.com': 1, ...}
```

I was thinking about `JsonProperty` first, but once implemented, realized that it could not be read and edited in Datastore Viewer - `<binary>` is displayed instead. Should I use `StringProperty` then?

Comment: Usage hint: what *data* is assigned to one vs the other? (I would not use a StringProperty, but rather consider it *opaque data*.)

Comment: why would you modify data in datastore viewer?

Comment: @user2864740, I am not sure if I understand your question. The data is given in the question - this is email of the user and according to this email counter.

Comment: @marcadian, the main idea is to view it (for debug purposes). Edit - just in some rare cases probably I would need to correct the data manually.

Comment: What is the real advantage of using one against the other? Does manually serializing json and storing as a StringProperty have any difference from just storing as JsonProperty and let ndb serialize and base64 encode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, StringProperty is an option, in some cases.  Use JSON.dumps() and JSON.loads() to convert.